# Menu button with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a menu with dropdown but dropdown won't work.

It my fiddle. there is a code for that button but it don't show. I don't know why. Here is my fiddle: 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2D7wn/)

```
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I use bootstrap 3.0 
Here is image how it looks like : 
[image]

Comment: put external resources on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove overflow:hidden of div and img from css and assign to .wrapper

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2D7wn/1/)

```
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 4em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 502px;overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Action</a>
           <ul><li>submenu 1 </li>
               <li>submenu 2 </li>
               <li>submenu 3 </li></ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>     
</ul>
```